# Trying to sum rows in a column but only sum the rows that are checked in a checklistbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a checkedlistbox that is populated with 'Parts' from my 'PartsHeaderTable', I need to grab only the parts that are checked and sum those part's cost that were checked to get an overall totalcost of all the parts selected in the checklistbox. I need to insert TotalCost into my OverAllHeaderTable.

I've got a 'PartNumber' column and a 'Cost' column in my PartsHeaderTable. I have a 'TotalCost' column in my OverAllHeaderTable.

This is the code I have so far and I'm only getting the cost of one of the part's cost in my TotalCosts when I select two parts to get TotalCosts:

```
If chkLstParts.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

    For Each item As Object In chkLstParts.CheckedItems
        Dim checkedItem As Integer

        checkedItem = Val(item)

        Dim PartsCostcmd As New SqlCommand("Select Sum(isnull(Cost, 0))FROM PartsHeaderTable Where Parts = @Parts", con)

        PartsCostcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parts", checkedItem) 

        TotalCost = PartsCostcmd.ExecuteScalar

    Next

    con.Close()

End If

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert INTO OverAllHeaderTable (TotalCost) Values( @TotalCost)", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalCost", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TotalCost
If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Any Help Is Appreciated!!!!!

Comment: At each loop you set the TotalCost with the value for the current loop checkedItem, so at the exit from the loop you have only the value for the last checkedItem. You need to sum TotalCost += PartsCostcmd.ExecuteScalar

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict.  Objects are not doubles and doubles are not integers

Comment: Haven't heard of Option Strict, how do I turn that on?

Comment: Thank you, Steve for the quick response after I posted the question. I'm new to this, how can I give you an upvote or whatever?

Comment: The [tour] - which you agreed to take when you signed up, covers how SO works including accepting answers and upvoting helpful posts to help others find good answers

Comment: looks like I can't accept a comment as an answer according to the tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the total Cost as your Part cost on each loop. Just change the line

```
 TotalCost = PartsCostcmd.ExecuteScalar
```

to

```
 TotalCost = TotalCost + PartsCostcmd.ExecuteScalar
```

and before the loop, initialize it as 0

```
TotalCost = 0
```